# How to change the domain range of an axis?

Tags: ggvis

How can I use the mapping functions on ggvis to determine the range of the data displayed?

For example given this code:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~disp, ~wt) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  scale_numeric("x", domain = c(50, 500), nice = FALSE)
```

How can I render a chart with max value=400 on the x-axis? I tried to change `domain=c(50, 400)`, but it still renders points for values > 400.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `filter` function in the dplyr package:

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  filter(disp < 400) %>%
  ggvis(~disp, ~wt) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  scale_numeric("x", domain = c(50, 400))
```

You may also consider the `clamp` argument:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~disp, ~wt) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  scale_numeric("x", domain = c(50, 400), clamp = TRUE)
```